# how to connect ejabbered server to android java code

Tags: android

how to connect `ejabbered` server to `android`

```
 ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("http://localhost:5280/admin");
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            connection.connect();
            connection.login("Test", "Test");// Log into the server
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**Smack**](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) Android Clientfor that. 
By using Smack creating a connection is as simple like

```
    // Create the configuration for this new connection
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
configBuilder.setResource("SomeResource");
configBuilder.setXmppDomain("jabber.org");

AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
// Connect to the server
connection.connect();
// Log into the server
connection.login();

...

// Disconnect from the server
connection.disconnect();
```

[Smack Documention](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/tree/master/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

[Smak 4.1.3](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.3/javadoc/) ServerName is the name of your server. ServerIp is the ip address of your server and mPort is port for xmpp server which is usually 5222.

And Make sure you have registered users for example in your case user "Test" should be registered.

```
 XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .setServiceName(serverName).setHost(serverIp)
                        .setPort(mport)
                        .setCompressionEnabled(false).build();
            XMPPTCPConnectionconn conn= new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
                    conn.connect();
                    conn.login(username,password);
```